# shiboken2 & PySide2 issues

Tags: user-interface, pyqt5, importerror, pyside2, shiboken2

I get this error when trying to run a PyQt5 Application, I keep getting it and I think it's when I use pyuic5 to export code from QT Designer and then try to run it.

```
from .shiboken2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have used `pip freeze` to find the versions of `shiboken2` and `pyside2` and they are both the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Python 3.7 + And it works.